# Convert List<Object> to Dictionary<int,Object> c#

Tags: c#

I have this List
 `List<LayerAnnotation>`
and i want to convert
 `Dictionary<int, LayerAnnotation>` .
I dont know how to map key(int) with every element of List .

Comment: Is the key the list index?

Comment: "I dont know how to map key(int) with every element of List ." you need to tell us how you want the key to be... index? random? some property from `LayerAnotation` ?

Comment: Yes i want to map list index to every index of LayerAnnotation .
  Like i did this : var dictionary = layerAnnotations.ToDictionary(x =>0, s => s);
But for 2nd entry of LayerAnnotation , same key (0 in this case) cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use some sort of Id as a key:

```
public class LayerAnnotation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Annotation { get; set; }
}

List<LayerAnnotation> items = new List<LayerAnnotation>() {
    new LayerAnnotation {Id = 1, Annotation = "Test1"},
    new LayerAnnotation {Id = 2, Annotation = "Test2"}
};
    
Dictionary<int, LayerAnnotation> dict = items.ToDictionary(i => i.Id );
```

Above ToDictionary method accepts information which property should be used as a Dictionary Key. In the above example it is Id.